# Duvida no Middleware Before do ControllerProvider do Silex

Tags: php, silex

Opa a todos,
Pessoal tenho varias classes que seguem esta estrutura:

```
class TestController implements ControllerProviderInterface {

public function connect(Application $app)
{
    $adm = $app['controllers_factory'];
    $adm->before(function() use($app){
        $login=new \JN\Core\Login($app);

        if($login::verificaLogin()['status']==true){
            $app['twig']->addGlobal('login', $login);                
        }else{
            return $app->redirect($app["url_generator"]->generate("adminLogin"));
        }
    });

    $adm->get('/ola', function() use($app) {
        $valores = $app['userService']->listarTudo();
        $passagem = [
            'tituloPagina'=>'Teste',
            'erros'=> ''
        ];
        return $app['twig']->render('/admin/abertura.twig', ['passagem'=>$passagem]);
    });

    return $adm;
}
```

}

So que a parte do Middleware Before no começo da classe se repete em todas e eu gostaria de saber como eu posso isolar esta parte do codigo em outra classe e injeta-la nas classes que eu precisar deste Middleware.
Codigo a ser removido e depois injetado:

```
$adm->before(function() use($app){
        $login=new \JN\Core\Login($app);

        if($login::verificaLogin()['status']==true){
            $app['twig']->addGlobal('login', $login);

        }else{
            return $app->redirect($app["url_generator"]->generate("adminLogin"));
        }
    });
```

No arquivo index.php eu monto as rotas assim:

```
$app->mount('/blog', new \JN\Controller\Admin\TestController());
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Acho que se você fizer isso resolve.

```
// index.php
$app->before(function() use($app){
        $login=new \JN\Core\Login($app);

        if($login::verificaLogin()['status']==true){
            $app['twig']->addGlobal('login', $login);

        }else{
            return $app->redirect($app["url_generator"]->generate("adminLogin"));
        }
    });

$app->mount('/blog', new \JN\Controller\Admin\TestController());
```

Dessa forma todos os controllers que usam mount usaram o mesmo before.

Comment: bão? OLha desta forma que você citou eu aplico o before para todos os controllers do projeto, mas na verdade eu preciso apenas na area administrativa onde eu criei um controller com o nome $admin, _$adm = $app['controllers_factory'];_. A minha dúvida é esta como eu aplico apenas para este controller em particular. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Pode-se criar um atributo middleware (before, after of finish) separado e injetar direto na rota/controller desejada. Assim:

```
$before = function (Request $request, Application $app) {
    // ...
};

$app->mount('/blog', new \JN\Controller\Admin\TestController())
->before($before);
```